# Next.js Button Hover Effect Not Working with Tailwind CSS (Dynamic Color)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm facing an issue with button hover behavior in a Next.js component using Tailwind CSS. The goal is to dynamically change the button background color on hover based on a color value stored in the component's state.

The code works perfectly in a React.js application, but the hover effect isn't triggered in Next.js.

```
"use client";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const BottomButtons = ({ onHeaderTextChange }) => {
  const [selectedButton, setSelectedButton] = useState("Delivery Rate");

  const handleButtonClick = (buttonText) => {
    setSelectedButton(buttonText);
    onHeaderTextChange(buttonText);
  };

  const buttons = [
    { text: "Delivery Rate", color: "#00E096" },
    { text: "Click Rate", color: "#0E9AFF" },
    { text: "Open Rate", color: "#BF83FF" },
    { text: "Bounce Rate", color: "#FF947A" },
    { text: "Issues", color: "#FA5A7D" },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-end mb-4">
      {buttons.map((button, index) => (
        <button
          key={index}
          className={`p-2 hover:bg-[${button.color}] border`}
          onClick={() => handleButtonClick(button.text)}
        >
          {button.text}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default BottomButtons;
```

**What I Tried:**

- I've verified that the button.color values are correct and correspond to Tailwind color names.
- I've checked for any conflicting styles using browser developer tools.
- I've ensured Tailwind is configured correctly and purged unused CSS.
- Expected Behavior:
- I expect the button background color to change dynamically based on the corresponding Tailwind color name within the hover:bg-[button.color] class when hovering over the button element.

**Additional Information:**

- I've confirmed the code works as intended in a pure React.js environment.
- I suspect the issue might be related to Next.js's server-side rendering (SSR) behavior.

Answer (score 0):

From [TailwindCSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names)

> #### Dynamic class names
>
> The most important implication of how Tailwind
> extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as
> complete unbroken strings in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names
> together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate
> the corresponding CSS:

So as the docs says, generating the classes on the fly like the way you are doing should not work.

Instead, there are multiple ways to fix the issue, one of them is from the docs: using `colorVariants`

```
function BottomButtons() {

  const buttons = [
    { text: "Delivery Rate", color: "red" },
    { text: "Click Rate", color: "blue" },
    // remaining ....
  ]

  const colorVariants = {
    blue: 'hover:bg-[#00E096]',
    red: 'hover:bg-[#0E9AFF]',
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-end mb-4">
      {buttons.map((button, index) => (
        <button
          key={button.text}
          className={`p-2 ${button.color} border`}
        >
          {button.text}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

However, for the sake of simplicity, I suggest to skip the extra step `colorVariants` and just easily make the `buttons` array like below:

```
const buttons = [
  { text: "Delivery Rate", color: "hover:bg-[#00E096]" },
  { text: "Click Rate", color: "hover:bg-[#0E9AFF]" },
  { text: "Open Rate", color: "hover:bg-[#BF83FF]" },
  { text: "Bounce Rate", color: "hover:bg-[#FF947A]" },
  { text: "Issues", color: "hover:bg-[#FA5A7D]" },
];

<button
key={button.text}
className={`p-2 ${button.color} border`}>
 {button.text}
</button>
```

I have created a simple example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-e9zuqn?file=app%2Fpage.tsx)